# comparing the keys for dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries (L1) and a dictionary (D1) in python:

```
L1 = [{'date': u'2017-06-14 18:46:40', 'value': u'148.01', 'id': u'8430'}, {'date': u'2017-06-14 18:46:40', 'value': u'133.03', 'id': u'681'}, {'date': u'2017-06-14 18:46:40', 'value': u'62.55', 'id': u'6151'}, {'date': u'2017-06-14 18:46:40', 'value': u'100.29', 'id': u'2089'}]

D1 = {u'7925': [u'538'], u'7927': [u'3819', u'7307'], u'8480': [u'1772', u'1772'], u'8481': [u'4384'], u'8482': [u'4725']}
```

How do I compare the key in D1 to the id in L1
I need to access the list in D1

Like:

```
for item in L1:
  if item['id'] in D1:
   print 'list: ',  D1[item['id']
   D1LST =  D1[item['id']]
   for d in D1LST:
     Do something
```

My print statement shows up blank

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Do you just want to see if there's a match? Or do you want to get the dict that matched and do something with it?

Comment: Please provide details on what is the problem you are trying to solve, to determine what approach would be ideal in this scenario. Also, can you show more of the code you attempted to try to perform this comparison to see where you are making your mistakes?

Comment: `[x for x in L1 if x['id'] in D1.keys()]`

Comment: @idjaw I updated the question

Comment: @ChrisJ Check the answers already posted and see if they solve your answer. If not, then you are going to have to explain further what it is you are looking for.

Comment: In this case how about : `[y for x,y in D1.iteritems() for item in L1 if x in item['id']]`

Comment: I want to access the list in D1 for each keep that matched a key in L1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps :

```
[y for x,y in D1.iteritems() for item in L1 if x in item['id']]
```

If input :

```
L1 = [{'date': u'2017-06-14 18:46:40', 'value': u'148.01', 'id': u'8430'}, {'date': u'2017-06-14 18:46:40', 'value': u'133.03', 'id': u'681'}, {'date': u'2017-06-14 18:46:40', 'value': u'62.55', 'id': u'6151'}, {'date': u'2017-06-14 18:46:40', 'value': u'100.29', 'id': u'2089'}]

D1 = {u'8430': [u'538'], u'7927': [u'3819', u'7307'], u'8480': [u'1772', u'1772'], u'8481': [u'4384'], u'8482': [u'4725']}
```

Output :

```
[[u'538']]
```

Comment: I don't understand the x,y... I just want to use the matching key to access the list in D1

Comment: (x, y) equi to (key, value)

Answer (score 0):

Get ids from L1 then Iterate D1 to find a match

```
ids = [d['id'] for d in L1]

for k in D1.keys(): 
  if(k in ids):
    # Whatever happens when there is a match
```

Comment: Mind your indentations! And just by looking i see no match there!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. Iterate through each element of `L1`, if the element's `id` is a key in `D1` then do something.

```
for element in L1:
    key = element['id']
    if key in D1:
        # Do Other Computations
        print D1[key]
```

The reason why nothing is being printed is because no `id` in `L1` exists in `D1`.

List of IDs in `L1`: `[u'8430', u'681', u'6151', u'2089']`

List of keys in `D1`: `[u'8480', u'7927', u'8482', u'7925', u'8481']`

As you can see, none of them match. So it makes sense that your output is empty.

Comment: It works for a bit then I get this error     key = item['id']
TypeError: string indices must be integers